# C# Serialization issues while mapping one version of a type to a different version of a type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-assembly

**Background** 
I have encountered a strange situation in my application that uses a 3rd party component. Quite a few classes in my application implements ISerializable interface to basically persist the object state back and forth. I face compatibility issues during the course of serialization when I serialize my app classes in one version and try to deserialize with a different version of 3rd party component.

**Issue** 
The latest release of the 3rd party component saw some major shuffling w.r.t types and assemblies.

**i.e.** for ex : 
 Earlier a Type **T1** found under the assembly **A1**. . Post new release, where the assembly **A1** has now been split to two different assemblies like for ex: **A11** and **A12**. And the type **T1** is now housed in **A12**

The type **T1** on deserialization, is trying to find assembly **A1**. But now since it has been moved to a different assembly like **A12** it is throwing SerializationException stating it is not able to find the Assembly **A1**.

**Things I tried:**

**1. SerializationBinder:** 
I used a SerializationBinder class which basically checked the incoming assemblyName and TypeName information and suitably routed to the correct assembly on deserialization.

**2. AssemblyResolve event using ResolveEventHandler delegate** 
Basically i can extract the assembly file name from the assembly’s identity and I can re-route the updated path where my application can find the assembly file using call Assembly.LoadFrom to load the assembly and return the resulting Assembly reference back from the ResolveEventHandler method

Although both of the above approach works to a certain extent. It is quite a task to supply the routing information to the correct assembly for all the types that are marked as serializable in my application. Not to mention this has to be updated again for future releases.

So I'm here to ask for help/suggestions/alternatives

Has anyone here has experienced such a situation ? 
How were you able to tackle such an issue ?
If you could be generous to shed some best practices and pitfalls to avoid when using Serialization with 3rd party components

Cheers and thanks in advance
VATSAG

Comment: What format of serialization was that ? Soap ?

Answer (score 0):

About BinaryFormatter:
[What are the deficiencies of the built-in BinaryFormatter based .Net serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703073/what-are-the-deficiencies-of-the-built-in-binaryformatter-based-net-serializati)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is more specific to .NET Serialization best practices. While my question is more related to handling serialization/deserialization of types which depend on different versions of 3rd party components.

Comment: Ok, got it and it is an entirely a different question... May be store your routing information in a config file ?  And then manually/auto update it when you need it?