# Binary serialization versioning issue

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, versioning, iserializable

I have a class implementing `ISerializable`. Old binary data cannot be deserialized after adding new field to that class due to the following error:

> SerializationException: No element named 'x' could be found.

Shouldn't serializer automatically assign `null` or `0` to that field in this case? I tried using `Attribute [OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]` but with the same result.

I can handle it by checking if field name exists in `SerializationEntry`
array but is this the right way to do it? Is there a better way?

Comment: Yet another reason against Binary serialization. Do you have a deserialization constructor or are you hoping the framework handles it by itself?

Comment: Yes, I do have a deserialization constructor. According to msdn documentation this should be handled by serializer. But I bet it is me doing something wrong...

Comment: In that case, you need to show your code.

Comment: If the `SerializationException` is being thrown from a call to `SerializationInfo.GetValue()` from within your own streaming constructor code, then yes, you have to either manually look through the serialization entries, or catch the exception.  Once you implement `ISerializable` then you have to do everything manually, attributes like `[OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]` no longer matter.

Comment: Bear in mind `SerializationInfo` was designed as part of .Net 1.0/1.1 (2003-2004) and hasn't really been improved since then.  Methods that obviously should be present like `SerializationInfo.TryGetValue()` simply don't exist.

Comment: Is it better than not to use the ISerializable?

Comment: It's better not to use `BinaryFormatter`.  See [What are the deficiencies of the built-in BinaryFormatter based .Net serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/703073/3744182).  But `ISerializable` itself isn't awful if you need manual control over serialization, it's just that `SerializationInfo` is missing some obviously useful methods.

Comment: Serializer should include version or other hint data in the serialized data stream so that the deserializer knows what it's looking at.